# how to aggregate counts in a bash one-liner

Tags: bash, unix, uniq

I often use `sort | uniq -c` to make count statistics.
Now, if I have two files with such count statistics, I would like to put them together and add the counts. (I know I could append the original files and count there, but lets assume only the count files are accessible).

For example given:

a.cnt:

```
   1 a
   2 c
```

b.cnt:

```
   2 b
   1 c
```

I would like to concatenate and get the following output:

```
   1 a
   2 b
   3 c
```

What's the shortest way to do this in the shell?

**Edit:**

Thanks for the answers so far!

Some possible side-aspects one might want to consider additionally:

- what if a, b, c are arbritrary strings, containing arbitrary white-spaces?
- what if the files are too big to fit in memory? Is there some `sort | uniq -c`-style command line option for this case that only looks at two lines at a time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can work for any given number of files:

```
$ cat a.cnt b.cnt | awk '{a[$2]+=$1} END{for (i in a) print a[i],i}'
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

So if you have let's say 10 files, you just have to do `cat f1 f2 ...` and then pipe this `awk`.

If the file names happen to share a pattern, you can also do ([thanks Adrian Frühwirth!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22383981/how-to-aggregate-counts-in-a-bash-one-liner#comment34028431_22384093)):

```
awk '{a[$2]+=$1} END{for (i in a) print a[i],i}' *cnt
```

So for example this will take into consideration all the files whose extension is `cnt`.

---

> Some possible side-aspects one might want to consider additionally:
>
> - what if a, b, c are arbritrary strings, containing arbitrary white-spaces?
> - what if the files are too big to fit in memory? Is there some `sort | uniq -c`-style command line option for this case that only looks at two lines at a time?

In that case, you can use the rest of the columns as indexes for the counter:

```
awk '{count=$1; $1=""; a[$0]+=count} END{for (i in a) print a[i],i}' *cnt
```

Note that in fact you don't need to `sort | uniq -c` and redirect to a `cnt` file and then perform this re-counting. You can do it all together with something like this:

```
awk '{a[$0]++} END{for (i in a) print a[i], i}' file
```

#### Example

```
$ cat a.cnt
   1 and some
   2 text here

$ cat b.cnt
   4 and some
   4 and other things
   2 text here
   9 blabla

$ cat *cnt | awk '{count=$1; $1=""; a[$0]+=count} END{for (i in a) print a[i],i}'
4  text here
9  blabla
4  and some
4  and other things
```

Regarding second comment:

```
$ cat b
and some
text here
and some
and other things
text here
blabla

$ awk '{a[$0]++} END{for (i in a) print a[i], i}' b
2 and some
2 text here
1 and other things
1 blabla
```

Comment: Or, you know, just skip the pipe :-)

Comment: @dhokas absolutely. Updated the post with the change, thanks for reporting!

Answer (score 5):

Using awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$1;next} $2 in a{a[$2]+=$1}1' a.cnt b.cnt
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$ awk '{a[$2]+=$1}END{for(i in a){print a[i], i}}' a.cnt b.cnt
1 a
2 b
3 c
```